# Traversing through list<list<object>> in C#

Tags: c#, class, iteration

I have a base class like:

```
  public class Data
  {
    public double F{ get; set; }
    public double S11R { get; set; }
    public double S21R { get; set; }
    public double S12R { get; set; }
    public double S22R { get; set; }
    public double S11I { get; set; }
    public double S21I { get; set; }
    public double S12I { get; set; }
    public double S22I{ get; set; }
 }
```

I also have a class like:

```
public class VTM
{
    public VTM()
    {
        Data = new List<List<Data>>();
    }

    public List<List<Data>> Data{ get; set; }
}
```

I create an instance of VTM in which there are 9 List(let us say they are A, B, C, D,...., I) and, each List has 45 Data instances.

Based on this class, I need to create another class by iterating through each element. I want to populate SLCTN11 property of VM class which is another type of class defined below.

```
public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        SLCTN11= new List<VMData>();
        SLCTN12= new List<VMData>();
        SLCTN21= new List<VMData>();
        SLCTN22= new List<VMData>();
      
    }
    public List<VMData> SLCTN11{ get; set; }
    public List<VMData> SLCTN12{ get; set; }
    public List<VMData> SLCTN21{ get; set; }
    public List<VMData> SLCTN22{ get; set; }
}



public class VMData
{
    public double F{ get; set; }
    public double R1 { get; set; }
    public double R2 { get; set; }
    public double R3 { get; set; }
    public double R4 { get; set; }
    public double R5 { get; set; }
    public double R6 { get; set; }
    public double R7 { get; set; }
    public double R8 { get; set; }
    public double R9 { get; set; }
    public double I1 { get; set; }
    public double I2 { get; set; }
    public double I3 { get; set; }
    public double I4 { get; set; }
    public double I5 { get; set; }
    public double I6 { get; set; }
    public double I7 { get; set; }
    public double I8 { get; set; }
    public double I9 { get; set; }
}
```

SLCTN11 is populated based on A,B,C,..,I and they consist of 45 rows each. SLCTN11 defined as follows:

```
Vm vm=new VM();

vm.SCLTN11.Add(new VMData(){
   F=A.Data.F,
   R1=A.Data.S11R,
   I1=A.Data.S11I,
   R2=B.Data.S11R,
   I2=B.Data.S11I,
   ...,
   R9=I.Data.S11R,
   I9=I.Data.S11I 

});
```

I want to accomplish it by iterating through VTM object via two foreaches.

```
foreach (var dt in vna.Data)
{
   //iterates from A to I
   foreach (var data in dt)
   {
       //iterates through 0 to 45 Data objects 
   }
}
```

but after iteration for A, I am not sure how to handle the iteration for altering the same SLCTN11 object from B to I to fill out the SCLTN11 list like the above definition.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I really can't understand what you are trying to achieve. What is the type of your SLCTN11? What is the pattern that each row is going to follow? Judging only by the first row you provided it's unclear how the other rows should be constructed. It would help if you could give more explanation.

Comment: You said that each of the "inner" lists has 45 instances of "Data". At the same time an instance of "SLCTN11" consists of 45 "rows".
So can an instance of SLCTN11 be created/filled by exactely one of those inner list (of 45 Data instances)?
or do you need data from multiple "inner" lists to fill one instance of "SLCTN11"?

Comment: @PharazFadaei updated my question, could you please have a look at it.

Comment: @lidqy I just added a class definition for SLCTN11. I wanted to basically explain my issue therefore wrote SLCTN11 as a class. Actually, it is not a class but a class property.  I updated my question, please have a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only provided what the first item of `SCLTN11` should look like, it is not easy to come up with a general pattern. However, based on the dimensions of `vna.Data` and the expected dimension of `vm.SCLTN11`, I guess I managed to understand what you want to achieve. If I'm not mistaken, you need the first item of `SCLTN11` to consist of the `S11R` and `S11I` values of only FIRST items in A,B,...,I collections. For the second item, you want the `S11R` and `S11I` values of all the SECOND items in A,B,...,I collections. And so on. If this is what you want, you can't easily achieve it with `foreach` loops. However, you can easily use `for` loops with indexes to do it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
{
    var data = new VMData
    {
        F = vna.Data[0][i].F
    };

    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        var rProperty = typeof(VMData).GetProperty("R" + (j + 1));
        var iProperty = typeof(VMData).GetProperty("I" + (j + 1));

        rProperty.SetValue(data, vna.Data[j][i].S11R);
        iProperty.SetValue(data, vna.Data[j][i].S11I);
    }

    vm.SLCTN11.Add(data);
}
```

Here I used reflection to set the values of `R1`, `R2`, ..., `R9` and `I1`, `I2`, ..., `I9` properties. However, if the performance of reflection is an issue, you can omit the inner loop and set the properties manually:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
{
    vm.SCLTN11.Add(new VMData
    {
        F = vna.Data[0][i].F, // Always A.F

        R1 = vna.Data[0][i].S11R,
        I1 = vna.Data[0][i].S11I,

        R2 = vna.Data[1][i].S11R,
        I2 = vna.Data[1][i].S11I,

        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pharaz. I tried the first one that you suggested and it worked. I did not know the way you solved it. Thank you very much.